# Call the method when the device is within 10 meters of the marker

Tags: java, android, geolocation, gps

In my app, I get the coordinates of my device. Now I'm trying to make it so that when the device is within a radius of 10 meters, the method is called. Found the addProximityAlert method. But there you need to pass the coordinates of the point I need, but I do not know how to link the marker I need and the position of the device. I have already created a broadcastreceiver. Please help with advice or an article.

```
public void getlocate() {
        if (flag) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.runline.workertrack");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, -1, intent, 0);
            try {
                enable = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (enable) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 5, listener);
                manager.addProximityAlert(0,0 , 100, -1, pendingIntent);
            }
    }
}
public boolean checkLocationPermission()
{
    int loc1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
List<String> listper = new ArrayList<>();
if(loc1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    listper.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
if(!listper.isEmpty()) {
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listper.toArray(new String[listper.size()]), 1);

}

    return true;
}

    class Locate implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                manager.removeUpdates(listener);
                shirota = "" + location.getLatitude();
                dolgota = "" + location.getLongitude();
                shir.setText(shirota);
                dolg.setText(dolgota);
                final Map<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                hashMap.put("shirota", shirota);
                hashMap.put("dolgota", dolgota);
                hashMap.put("id", "1");
                reference.setValue(hashMap);
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.runline.workertrack");
                registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    }
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
        String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
        Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
        if(entering){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are here!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Show us some code, THEN we can help you

Comment: Added in question)